# GCC/Clang/MSVC extensions for getting C struct member name at compile time?

Tags: c, struct

This question is usually asked for a run-time context (and most of the times for the purpose of achieving reflection), but I'm interested in achieving it at compile time instead.

Is there any extension in any C compiler that lets you get, at compile time, the name of the n-th member in a struct?

I know I can use preprocessor tricks for that (ie: by creating a macro that defines structs while doing hidden plumbing), but it would require to turn C syntax into cluttered macro invocations.

Imagine this (which needs to be compiled either with MSVC, or with the `-fms-extensions` option if using GCC or Clang, because it's not C11 anonymous structs, but MS anonymous structs):

```
struct childone{
int a;
int b;
};

struct childtwo{
int c;
int d;
};

struct container{
struct childone;
struct childtwo;
};
```

And the problem is: Find the offset of `childtwo` inside `container`.

So, I want something like `offsetof(struct container, nameof_firstmemberof(struct childtwo))`

Comment: Both GCC and Clang allow you to write plugins that can extract such information from the generated AST. But explaining in detail how to write such a plugin is maybe a bit much. Look at e.g. Clangs `libtooling`, it is well documented and you should be able to achieve this easily.

Comment: Succinctly, No.   Why would you want to do so?  This is probably an XY problem.  What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I want to get the offset (with `offsetof`) of an anonymous struct which is included into another struct (using not C11 anon structs, but the tagged version achievable with `-fms-extensions`). Thus, I want something like `offsetof(struct container, nameofFirstmemberof(struct child))`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us by example what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'd recommend against using the MS extension. It looks bizarre to me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'd certainly prefer to avoid using vendor-specific extensions and use only standard C18. However, AFAIK, this MS extension is the only way for including anonymous structs that were previously defined (and not defined in-place, like C11 dictates). IMHO, here the C committee lost a great opportunity, because with C11 anon structs I need to use macros and get clumsy code, while the MS extension does it clean and tidy. If I want to avoid the MS extension, I guess my only way is to use a preprocessor that generates C code from another input. And I think that would be worse, IMHO.

Comment: "Find the offset of childtwo inside container." It may simply be `sizeof(struct childone)` in the absence of padding.

Answer (score 0):

why make it difficult for your self, suggest:

```
struct container
{
    struct childone child1;
    struct childtwo child2;
};
```

Per wikipedia:

```
Use offsetof() to find the offset from the start of z or from the start of x . 

#include <stddef.h> size_t offsetof(type, member);
```

offsetof() returns the offset of the field member from the start of the structure type.